# Finding a color in a column and getting the data from another column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an spreadsheet like the following.

```
      A             B             C
7- Test                       [red]
8- Test1                      [yellow]
9- Test2                      [red]
```

So, I'm trying to pass a loop in the column C, starting on C7. When it gets the color red, I should be able to get the values from column A, which are Test and Text2.

Here is the related code (it's **not** entering on the if)

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()   
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var dataCor = s.getRange('C7:C').getBackgrounds();
Browser.msgBox(dataCor);                      //Here I show the codes from the colors.
var dataValor = s.getRange('A7:A').getValues();
Browser.msgBox(dataValor);                   //Here I show the values from the column A.

var list = [];
var n = 0;
var n2 = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < dataCor.length; i++)
{
 n = n + 1;

 if(dataCor == '#cc0000') 
 {  
  list[n2] = s.getRange('A7'+n-1).getValue();
  n2++;
 }
}  
Browser.msgBox(list);
```

PS: If you guys have any suggestions, please tell me.

PS1: Just to knowledge, is there any function that ignores the weekend days on a math? For example, if I get the date 22 of february, I know that 20 and 21 should be ignored so people would be able to work from 15 to 19. Anyway, it's not related to the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays you get from your `getValues()` statements are 2D arrays, in other words, arrays of arrays.

In you Logger you should see something like that : `[[xx],[yy],[zz],...]`

so your comparison should compare the content of the array at the desired index and not - as you did - the entire 2D array.

In your script replace

```
if(dataCor == '#cc0000')
```

with

`if(dataCor[n][0] == '#cc0000')`

and similarly when you add the result to the output list :

```
list[n2] = dataValue[n]
```

which I would replace be using the [array.push method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
list.push(dataValue[n])
```

And in the end, when you get your list array write it in one single step to your sheet column using something like

```
s.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list)
```

---

### EDIT

Following iJay's answer which is using spreadsheet service calls in the loop (which is a bad idea because it is very slow - see [best practices here-](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) )

here is his code modified for a better efficiency ;

```
function getValueByColor(){
   var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var myRangeValues = s.getRange('A7:C').getValues();
   var myRangeColors = s.getRange('A7:C').getBackgrounds();
   Logger.log(myRangeColors)
   var list = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < myRangeValues.length; i++) {
      if(myRangeColors[i][2] == '#cc0000'){ // idx 2 is 3rd column = C
       list.push([myRangeValues[i][0]]) // grab value in column A
     }
   }
   Browser.msgBox(list);
 }
```

---

**Edit 2**

To get col A and B in the result list simply change this line :

```
list.push(myRangeValues[i][0]+' | '+myRangeValues[i][1] ) // grab value in column A and B
```

note : since Browser.msgBox does not handle "new line" I'd suggest using HTML to show it the way you want.

Code :

```
   ...   
   var list = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < myRangeValues.length; i++) {
      if(myRangeColors[i][2] !== '#cc0000'){ // idx 2 is 3rd column = C
       list+=myRangeValues[i][0]+' | '+myRangeValues[i][1] +'<br>' // grab value in column A and B
     }
   }
  var result= HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(list)
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(result, 'result')
 }
```

Comment: Got it. it's pretty fast, ty. But what if I have to show more than 1 value in the msgbox? For example, a second list called list2. So, in the messagebox, I would have something like: _Browser.msgBox(list,list2);_ . and, for customizing it, would be nice if it appears separated by a line. For example, list1Element, list2Element and then it skips the line to show  list1Element2, list2Element2.  Not sure I wen clear, but that is it. **PS:** I already have the list2 stored.

Comment: I tried using: _SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(list1, list2,0);_ but it shows first the elements from list1, then  from list2. So, I did try _SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(list1, list2,0);_ but, as expected, it results in the same. So, I need to show something like: Xlist1,Xlist2, Ylist1, Ylist2. BUT, everytime I show as element from list2 I should be able to skip the line as well.

Comment: Another option is to store both lists in only one list. But I'm not able to show two elements and then skip the line.

Comment: sorry but I don't really understand the issue you have... list is a 2 D array that can be written in a column as it is. What would you exactly expect to get ? (please show an example if possible)

Comment: In the first question, imagine column B has it's own values. So, instead of only getting the values from column A, I should be able to get from both of them, which I already did in two separated lists. Now, I should be able to show it on a messageBox. Imagine that list1 contains: [test,test2,test3] and list2 contains: [wow,wow2,wow3]. So, in the messagebox, it would be: test, wow THEN skip the line. Shows test2,wow2 THEN skip the line, and proceed this way. After showing every two values, always skip the line in the msgBox. I believe now it's clear.

Comment: I changed the display mode to HTML. I you already have data in a 2cond list simply add it item by item in the for loop and use <br> to create a CR. You can evan make it look better with an HTML table or whatever you like.

Comment: Perfectly! Could you explain the CR part? Not sure I got it.

Comment: sorry, I wrote CR for "chariot return", in other words, "new line" (even if it is not exactly the same... that was an abusive simplification ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I agreed to @serge-insas,

rather than going through two arrays for background and value, we can use same range. Just a thought

```
function getValueByColor()
{
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var myRange = s.getRange('A7:C');
var list = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= myRange.getNumRows(); i++) 
{
  // 3 -column c : 
  if(myRange.getCell(i,3).getBackground() == '#cc0000')
  {
    //1- column A
    list.push(myRange.getCell(i,1).getValue())
  }
}
//debugger;
Browser.msgBox(list);
}
```